# backprop in merged models

Tags: python, keras, backpropagation, generative-adversarial-network

I am working on Conditional GANs and my generator and discriminator both have two inputs and use merged models like this:-

```
z = Input(shape=(100,))
  temp = Input(shape=(384,))

  generator=Generator()
  img = generator([z,temp])

  valid = discriminator([img,temp])

  combined = Model([z,temp], valid)
  combined.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

DCGAN is being used to classify and generate images conditional to the "temp" embedding and I am using Adam "optimizer = Adam(0.0001, 0.5)" for both models.

GEN is like takes input noise "z" and "temp" merges them and makes 128x128x3 images. Disc takes image and performs conv2d on it and then reshapes "temp" to 1,128,3 and merges both and further applies conv2d and outputs a sigmoid unit. My question is that during backprop how are weights updated of a merged model, lets say of Disc here:-

```
  inp1 = Input(shape=(128,128,3),name='inp1')
  inp2 = Input(shape=(384,),name='inp2')
  d2=Reshape(target_shape=(1,128,3))(inp2)


  d1 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same")(inp1)
  d1=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d1)
  d1=Dropout(0.25)(d1)

  d1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same")(inp1)
  d1=BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(d1)
  d1=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d1)
  d1=Dropout(0.25)(d1)

  d1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same")(inp1)
  d1=BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(d1)
  d1=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d1)
  d1=Dropout(0.25)(d1)

  d1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same")(inp1)
  d1=BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(d1)
  d1=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d1)
  d1=Dropout(0.25)(d1)


  d1 = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same")(inp1)
  d1=BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(d1)
  d1=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d1)
  d1=Dropout(0.25)(d1)

  d1=Flatten()(d1)
  d1=Dense(768, activation="relu")(d1)
  d1=Reshape(target_shape=(2,128,3))(d1)

  output=concatenate(
    [
        d1,
        d2,
    ]
    ,axis=1
  )


  d1 = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same")(output)
  d1=BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(d1)
  d1=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d1)
  d1=Dropout(0.25)(d1)

  d1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same")(inp1)
  d1=BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(d1)
  d1=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d1)
  d1=Dropout(0.25)(d1)

  d1 = Conv2D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same")(inp1)
  d1=BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(d1)
  d1=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d1)
  d1=Dropout(0.25)(d1)

  d1=Flatten()(d1)

  output=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(d1)
  model=Model(
    inputs=[
      inp1,
      inp2
    ],
    outputs=[
      output
    ]
  )
  model.summary()
  img = Input(shape=(128,128,3))
  text=Input(shape=(384,))
  validity = model([img,text])

  return Model([img,text], validity)
```

And my disc loss starts from 2.02 and goes to around 6.7 in 150 epochs and loss of Gen decreases from 0.80 to 0.00024 in 150 epochs and I am getting garbage, how can I improve my architecture? And I was wondering that maybe backprop doesn't work well in merged models because it becomes a lot complicated.
I am using batchnorm, leaky relu, conv2d + stride, no pooling layers and label smoothing though.

Comment: Are you taking care of setting parts of your GAN as untrainable? You're not supposed to train the entire network together.

Comment: Yes I am making disc as non trainable for combined model.

Comment: Before compiling? (This is important)

Comment: Yes before compiling discriminator